# ASP.NET web application (.NET Framework)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imnAc.png)

How can I create an ASP.NET web application (.NET Framework) using Visual Studio 2022 Developer Edition and target .NET Framework 7 or 8, as the current options only include .NET Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8?

My Visual Studio version is 17.8.5

I tried to modify and try to download these version but it didn't work also I tried using (Microsoft.NET.UpgradeAssistant.vsix) but it also didn't work

Comment: Latest .NET Framework is 4.8.1 , You are asking .NET 7 & .NET 8 isn't it ?

Comment: .NET 7 / 8 are .NET **Core** versions - those are handled by the ASP.NET **Core** templates. The legacy/full .NET Framework only went up to v4.8.1 - no further. With this full/legacy template, you ***CANNOT*** create an app for .NET 7 / 8 ..

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework and .NET are two different frameworks.

For details, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

The .NET Framework 7 and 8 you are talking about should be .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0.

If you are creating ASP.NET with .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0, you should select the ASP.NET Core project type when creating the project:

[image]

This way you can choose .NET 7.0 or .NET 8.0.

[image]

If you still cannot find .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0, it should be that you have not installed .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0. You can use Visual Studio Installer to install .NET 7.0 and .NET 8.0.

[image]

[image]